# Sistema de mensagem (GCM) para aplicação local

Tags: java, google, google-cloud-messaging

Estou atrás de algum sistema como por exemplo o Google Cloud Messaging, para enviar notificações à uma aplicação local, um supervisório feito em java, rodando localmente (ele por sua vez conectado a um microcontrolador).

A ideia era que esse supervisório não precisasse ficar enviando solicitações para o Web Service, para saber se há alguma ação para ele executar. Para aplicações mobile existe o GCM, mas para essa minha aplicação local não consegui encontrar nada que faça o trabalho como o GCM.

Caso não exista terei que estipular um tempo e ciclicamente mandar solicitação para o Google Cloud pela aplicação local e requisitar as ações que eu tenho, porem dessa forma haverá solicitações demasiadas, porque não terei ações a serem executadas toda vez que a aplicação pedir para o Google Cloud.